# embedded javascript into an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I'm trying to implement Google Calendar on my site into an iframe, I know Google has its own code for this, but the Calendar isn't editable then.

I have tried a few things, but I don't have the knowledge. Can anyone help me with this please?

```
<style> 
input.createtable {
display:none;
}
</style>
  <script language="JavaScript"> 
<!--
writeConsole = function(content) {
 top.consoleRef=window.open('','myconsole2',
  'width=800,height=800'
   +',menubar=0'
   +',toolbar=0'
   +',status=0'
   +',scrollbars=1'
   +',resizable=1')
 // top.consoleRef.document.open("text/html","replace");
 top.consoleRef.document.writeln(
'<iframe <script src="http://www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?
url=http://addthisshare.com/calendar3.xml&amp;up_calendarSources=&
amp;up_calendarColors=&amp;up_calWkst=2&amp;up_calDefaultView=MONTH
&amp;up_calHeight=375&amp;up_calShowPrint=0&amp;up_calShowCals=1
&amp;up_calShowTabs=1& amp;up_calShowDate=1&amp;up_calShowNav=1
&amp;up_calNoActive=&amp;up_calTimeZone=Europe%2FAmsterdam
&amp;synd=open&amp;w=805&amp;h=390&amp;title=Google+Calendar
&amp;border=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gmodules.com%2Fig%2Fimages%2F
&amp;output=js"></script>"></iframe>'
 )
 top.consoleRef.document.close()
}
//-->
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about the error?

Answer (score 0):

An iframe has a src-attribute that is the url to page you want to display inside of the iframe.

Code that you put between the `<iframe>`and `</iframe>` will not be seen, unless the browser does not support iframes.

So, you cannot expect both the above techniques to work at the same time. Either your src-url will be used or your code between the iframe-tags will be used; never both. This means that there is no way to "embed a javascript into an iframe". The only way to get your script in there would be to add it to the source page that you're loading into the iframe.

On a final note, I don't think you really know what you are asking for here. The title of your question is probably not what you want to do, but we'll need a little more information to solve your actual problem.

**EDIT**

I think I have a better grasp of what you're asking now. What you should do is to forget the iframe for a moment and just focus on getting the events to work. When you have that working, put it into a file of its own and reference that file via the src-attribute of the iframe. Nothing should be "put inside the iframe" by adding code in the iframe-tag itself.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to add a google calendar to my website, this is possible, but then it's read-only, I need to add events to it.

Comment: I suppose google must provide an interface for that somehow, so that you can add things to the url to configure the behavior of the calendar. I don't think it can be solved with some generic web dev technique.

Comment: I think I wasn't clear enough. Google does provide a code, the problem is that you can't add events to the calendar.

Comment: Ok, made an edit to my answer. You should not focus on the iframe for now. Just make a new page where you get this to work, without the iframe. This will narrow your problem down. If you still cant get it to work, it's time for a new question, because then it has nothing to do with iframes :)

Answer (score 0):

The [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) prevents third parties from writing scripts that can insert data into arbitrary websites.

If Google do not provide an API for this, then it cannot be done.